# ¿Se puede hacer que un archivo en especifico siempre de conflicto en git?

Tags: git, gitlab

Estoy buscando una solución a un tema de mezcla de ramas, pero no quiero utilizar el git ignore ya que el archivo si que es modificable.

El tema es que tengo un archivo de configuración que es editable y quiero que lo sea, pero este archivo de configuración es diferente en cada rama.

Por eso tengo miedo que haciendo merge de una rama a otra se sobre escriba o alguien sin darse cuenta lo modifique.

entonces lo que quiero hacer es que ese archivo siempre de conflicto
seria algo así :

.miarchivo.yml master --> conflicto  <-- .miarchivo.yml dev

y que habiéndolo modificado o no siempre de conflicto obligándote a descartar los cambios solo cundo se haga merge.
¿Es esto posible?

cualquier otra solución que se os ocurra también será contemplada.

De momento he encontrado este tutorial pero yo no quiero que se resuelva solo lo que quiero es que siempre de conflicto y que avise a quien este realizando el merge.

https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/git-como-evitar-que-las-mezclas-de-ramas-cambien-ciertos-archivos

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que *siempre* de conflicto, coloca una linea diferente (un comentario, por ejemplo) como la primera linea del archivo.... de esa forma, si se trata de hacer *merge* de dichas ramas, vas a tener un conflicto obligado.... *pero* esto no evita que alguien haga un cherry-pick. En realidad no es buena idea llevar archivos configurables *de verdad* en las ramas. Lo que se lleva normalmente es un sample y los archivos **"de verdad"** se ignoran.

Comment: Esto es cierto pero son archivos de configuración .yml para el despliegue

Comment: Lo correcto seria que no tuvieras varios archivos de despliegue, y que con la herramienta externa que uses (jenkins, circleci...) Despliegues según que caso en el entorno. A muy malas, define tantos archivos como entornos tengas, ponles de nombre dev.yml, prod.yml... y luego en tu script de despliegue llama al que lo necesite. Así no tiene por qué darte conflicto